# Swift stored data in Firebase database not appearing in tableview

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a restaurant rating app in Swift for users to post comments for certain restaurants. The app does not require users to sign-up or log-in, thus I don't think I need a userID. I can successfully direct users comments to specific restaurants in the database, thus every restaurant has its own comment section(stored as locationName below).Comment adding works without a problem. Nevertheless, I can't seem to display the comments from the firebase database into the app. Here is my code, I'd appreciate any help, thank you very much in advance!

```
var comments = [String]()
var locationName = String() // created a specific node for each restaurant to display comments in the database
var ref: DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?


func loadComments() { //in viewDidLoad

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    databaseHandle = ref?.child("comments").child(locationName).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let comment = snapshot.value as? String

        if let actualComment = comment {

            self.comments.append(actualComment)

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    })


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return comments.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "CellFour")
    cell.textLabel!.text = comments[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Do you have security rules on your Firebase Database? The fact that u are not authenticating might cause a problem. Go to Firebase Console - Database - Security Rules and check if unauthenticated users can access your DB.

Comment: @GalShahar In rules, both read and write is set to true. I don't want users to create an account to comment, thus I'm not sure how I can further improve security.

Comment: Not even a single person knows what I'm doing wrong? :-(

Comment: try to print the comment as pulled from the database. add print("Comment", comment) after "let comment = snapshot.value as? String". Do you see something? or it prints nothing. I think there's a problem with your cellForRowAt function

Comment: @GalShahar just after "let comment = snapshot.value as? String" I inserted print("comment",comment) and I got comment nil How can I fix this problem?

Comment: OKAY!!!! I finally found the answer!!

Comment: what was it????

Comment: @GalShahar I found out that in my database, the users comments were stored in a node called commentText which was at comments>locationName>userID(don't need)->commentText thus I added the following and it worked! Yay!!                                                                                                         let insideComment = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "commentText")
                   let comment = insideComment.value as? String